# Google Docs Publish to the Web Data parsing

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, export-to-csv

I have a trouble with parsing of data from google spreadsheet api. I have a spreadsheet with 3 pages and I need to get data from there and parse them to array where key is cell position and value is value of cell.

When I go to File->Publish to the web with option "All sheets" and target format is CSV seperated with comas I get a link which is targeting data with just values of cells and just from first page.

Here is any way how to get data from all sheets and with information where are placed in document (cell name (code))?

Comment: It depends on how you want to use the data. There is a rather simple JavaScript API that allows you to access the data of a published (not exported) spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Spreadsheet API, for example using its [Java Library](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html)

or you can use Google Apps Script and its [spreadsheet methods](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/service_spreadsheet.html)

both of them are giving you the ability to have your data live in Google spreadsheet and at the same time access it from other clients or sites. You don't need to *export* it and lose the ability to have it updated across all your clients.